# How to add a integrity check on mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, constraints, workbench, integrity

I'm new to mySQL and I'd like to add a integrity check (or constraint? Sorry I'm italian) in my database.
Let me explain: I have two tables

```
Workshop (location, numPlaces, numOperations)
Operation (idoperation, workLocation, ...)
```

**numPlaces** represents the maximum number of operations the workshop can afford. I created a trigger that everytime I insert a new record in **Operation**, the **numOperations** of Workshop referred to that specific location is increased by 1.

Now what I'd like to do is: when `numOperations = numPlaces`, if I try to insert a new record to Operation, the system must tell me that I can't. Basically, it can't be possible that `numOperations > numPlaces`

Is there a way to achieve that? Sorry if I can't provide codes, but I literally have no idea where should I go to create these types of CHECKS. Hope you can help me!

Comment: chekc only work in mysql 8, so which version are you using, but that will only work for the one table

Comment: I'm using mySQL Workbench 8.0

Comment: Check constraints only work within a table, so you must use a trigger for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you must have set the workshop with the correct number of places.
And you should have a routine, that diminishes the number of operations so that you can enter new operation in one workshop

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Workshop 
> (location Text, numPlaces int , numOperations int
> )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Workshop VALUES ('A',9,8)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Operation (idoperation int, workLocation Text)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER before_Operation_insert
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON Operation FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE Placescount_ INT;
>     DECLARE Operationscount_ INT;
>     
>     SELECT numPlaces, numOperations
>     INTO Placescount_,Operationscount_
>     FROM Workshop WHERE location = NEW.workLocation;
>     
>     IF Placescount_ < Operationscount_ THEN
>         UPDATE Workshop
>         SET numOperations = numOperations + 1  WHERE location=new.workLocation ;
>     ELSE
>         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
>       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Maximum Number of Operarations reached in location ';
>     END IF; 
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Operation VALUES (1,'A')
> ```
>
> ```
> Maximum Number of Operarations reached in location
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c6874a86d3899da5fc65525bae0bfddf)*

Comment: Thanks!! This works!! At first it gave me ERROR 1175: 1175: You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column, then I added a WHERE location=new.workLocation under SET numOperations = numOperations+1; and it works perfectly. Had no idea I could use still trigger to report errors!